# Auto-generated primary key in sql database based on other filled field

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to have unique generated primary key that will take info from other field to create that code. 
For example, let say I would like to generate student ID based on year, and student's name, so my code will consist of string that has 3 letter and 4 digit. 
Student name: Jone
year: 2015
so the generated code will be something like: jon2015

Please advice me how I should do it?

Answer (score 0):

I built a Student Info System based on MySQL. I can tell you right away that building a unique ID based off a date and a name is the fastest way to get duplicates.

I suggest you generate the student IDs as a unique Int, just start the count at a high number, so you don't have an ID of 0001 or 1.

If you need a visually nicer representation of their ID, you can do something like:

```
[first initial][last name][last 4 of unique ID]
```

This will give you a more visually pleasing ID, but it will be based off a unique number. So JSmith1234

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful reply. I would like to ask is it possible to extract initial from the first name? or the user needs to fill it as they are typing their first and last name as well?

Comment: You can get the first initial from either MySQL query or your programming language query. From MySQL: "SELECT LEFT(subject , 1) FROM tbl" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left